# CSS Width equal to the height, not vice versa

Tags: css

for my web project is importent, that the **width** of my div **was equal to hight**, **not vice versa**, becouse height is relative and set to 80%. Something like:

```
.key{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 80%;
    width: *height*;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Thank's for help.

Comment: Can you please make the question more clear?

Comment: Please use **aspected ratio** in css https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp

Comment: what is your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way using CSS!

If you set your width depending on the parent container you can set the height to 0 and set padding-bottom to the percentage which will be calculated depending on the current width:

```
.key {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
padding-bottom: 20%;
}
```